# PHP returns only half of my results from mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json

I have a fairly large call I have to make to join 4 tables and get 50 rows.  When I do the pull on my PHP server it does the pull in 0.0013 seconds, which is good.  So I try to call the PHP from my iOS device to get the records and sometimes I get them, sometimes I get half.

Here is my PHP SQL code.

```
$sql = "SELECT NF.id, NF.type, NF.groupid, NF.classid, NF.videoid, NF.lessonid, NF.text, NF.path, NF.datetime, Groups.name as groupname, Groups.imagepath as groupimage, Classes.title as classname, Classes.imagepath as classimage, Videos.title as videoname, Videos.videopath as videopath, Lessons.title as lessonname, Lessons.imagepath as lessonimage   
     FROM NewsFeed as NF
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups on (NF.groupid=Groups.id)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Classes on (NF.classid=Classes.id)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Videos on (NF.videoid=Videos.id) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Lessons on (NF.lessonid=Lessons.id)
     WHERE $searchstring 
     ORDER BY NF.datetime DESC LIMIT 50";

$request = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$arr = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($request)){
    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($request)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }
}

// Return Array
echo '{"newsfeed":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

mysql_close($link);
```

Now when I echo the json_encoded array, sometimes i get the entire array starting from "newsfeed": and other times I get something like this:

> **2014-04-24 23:07:09.574 ProgramName[6573:60b] our programming theory...","path":"http://site.com/LMS/NewsFeedPictures/IMG2014170220465189.PNG","datetime":"2014-02-17 20:46:56","groupname":"LMS for iOS","groupimage":"http://site.com/LMS/GroupThumbnails/LMS.jpg","classname":null,"classimage":null,"videoname":** ... *(and more and more records until the end.)*

As you can see, that spot where the content string starts is the middle of my data!

So the question is why is the PHP only returning partial data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some checking, double checking and some more testing I came to the conslusion that it was not my PHP after all, it was my NSURLConnection.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
```

You CANNOT rely on this method bringing back whole data, it will break on some occasions.  Therefore you must implement an NSMutableData set and append the data like this...

```
if(arrData != nil){
  [arrData appendData:data];
}
```

And in the connection did finish delegate, do this...

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if (arrData != nil) {
        //Some method to return or use arrData
        arrData = nil;
    }
}
```

That way you will always receive the full data.  Thanks @Robotys for the help and new tools!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.

My main culprit at the time was a double quote (") in a string within the returned data from mysql. It invalidate the json string when it arrive at js call.

try to validate the json generated from the php through many [json validator](https://www.google.com/search?q=validate+json&oq=validate+json&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2166j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8). My favourite is [jslint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: So I did an error_log(json_encode($arr)) and put it in jslint and the JSON is valid.  But when the script echos the json my app only receives the broken data...im determined to fix this.  Thanks for the tip, I will be using jslint more often.

Comment: Noted. Then another theory is the json string was cut in half in between server and client. To prove this, try echo some large string other than the json string and view it in client js.

If it was cut in half like json string then we can confirmed something happen during the data transfer (which is unlikely) and can proceed to get deeper on that.

Comment: Echoed an extremely long string and it wasnt split.  Could it be the way I echo the array?

Comment: At this point I actually think there is something wrong with the way I am receiving the data from the NSMutableRequest.  I may have to use NSMutableData rather than just NSData...

Comment: I did some more digging last night and found that my data comes back in chunks sometimes.  Not sure why this is happening, but it is only in large returns.